# QT5: How can I change the size of a window from minimized to normal?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, c++14, qt5.5

My program automatically run at startup. My programs start minimized.

Example:

[image: My program run at startup minimized]

I use this commands to do this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    QRect r1(QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry(this).center().x()-300,
             QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry(this).center().y()-300, 100, 200);

    MainWindow::setGeometry(r1);

    srand(std::time(0));

    ui->setupUi(this);

    MainWindow::showMinimized();

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(MyTimerSlots()) );
    timer->start(5000);
}
```

But if it's now eight o'clock pm (20:00), I want to see the program in its normal size. I want to see something like that:

[image]

**My attempt to find solution:**
I use this command MainWindow::showNormal(); but without success

```
void MainWindow::MyTimerSlots()
{
qDebug() << "Timer..."<<QTime::currentTime().hour();

if (QTime::currentTime().hour() == 20 ){
    //MainWindow::showFullScreen();
    MainWindow::showNormal();

}

}
```

How can I change the size of a window from minimized to normal at 20 p.m.?

**Update:**

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include <QWidget>

#include <QTimer>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    QTimer *timer;

public slots:
    void MyTimerSlots();


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


#include <QDebug>

#include <QStyle>
#include <QDesktopWidget>

#include <QTime>
#include <QDate>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QRect r1(QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry(this).center().x()-300,
           QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry(this).center().y()-300, 100, 200);

    setGeometry(r1);
    srand(std::time(0));
    showMinimized();

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(MyTimerSlots()) );
    timer->start(5000);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

 void MainWindow::MyTimerSlots()
{
    qDebug() << "Timer..."<<QTime::currentTime().minute();

    //MainWindow::showFullScreen();

    showNormal();
    MainWindow::activateWindow();
    MainWindow::raise();

    //MainWindow::activateWindow();

}
```

Comment: On OS with normal GUI shell, [`QWidget::activateWindow()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#activateWindow) should be enough. If not, add `raise()`. On Ubuntu's Unity and other ill-conceived byproducts it may not work.

Comment: Yes, I try activateWindow() and raise() and it's not work

Comment: What *does* happen when `showNormal` is called -- anything?  Have you run your application under a debugger to make sure it *is* called (just checking)?

Comment: "What does happen when showNormal is called -- anything?" Nothing. This is my function: void MainWindow::MyTimerSlots()
{
qDebug() << "Timer..."<<QTime::currentTime().hour();
MainWindow::showNormal();

} I see hours with qDebug so my function MyTimerSlots() works and showNormal() is called but nothing happens

Comment: I updated my post and added the full code of my program

Comment: Maybe I need to install Ubuntu 17 because: "Since Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal Ubuntu has used Unity as its default user interface for the desktop, but following the release of Ubuntu 17.10 it will move to the GNOME 3 desktop instead, as work on Unity ends". I will have GNOME 3 and I will not have Unity.

Comment: Could you show me how to get your app started automatically?

Comment: Yes, I can show you. This is my video with this program http://www.fileconvoy.com/gf.php?id=ge3bc48daeb9dbca4999974065.10475666a6b17c3f2349f8a&sts=1498565375463281494141ade85774ef5d65bd917ce1b1d490    If you need more information please write to me